# Multiple correction for 3 different models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons

The [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26254886) I am reading gives a table of results for 3 different models:

[image]

The paper doesn't explain how the correction is performed, and it clearly isn't Bonferroni. Does someone have an idea how this correction is performed?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't diligent enough before posting the question, as the answer lies in the RobustSNP publication, and not the general knowledge of multiple testing corrections:

[Robust Association Tests Under Different Genetic Models,
Allowing for Binary or Quantitative Traits and Covariates](https://9e9bab3c-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/honcheongso/publications/RobustSNP.PDF?attachauth=ANoY7crqMc01WBE53uaQkopl1fld_6SpR1yMWS-42CGNA7b2bJWj-sql1txfCoa7SkeUl1GpQGkhQh5v4mQIdvslFp15VF06Wk-S6uHUA6tNFncglesziF9WwBFNz-kH8hlOLQ_xtP4VUW-kfEaBkX4oK0ZKR3u3g1UDQn24i1BuXOGMK_kn6pwwtj89gm8S1-HS-wzoIJ0qzc8827HCu_DI31RfG_YpSqGZYa6_qtoiKK1y3DCRV6w%3D&attredirects=0)

Here they explain their MAX3 correction, which estimates the covariance matrix of different genetic models.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: OK.  I looked at this for quite some time yesterday and was convinced they had done something wrong or used a non-standard approach for error correction.  It does indeed seem they used some non-standard approach contained in a non-standard R package.  Glad to see you figured this out!  Thanks for posting the answer.